# Dynamic page adding method with css

Tags: javascript, css, dynamic, mmenu

I am currently developing a dynamic menu using jQuery.mmenu plugin.

The definition (nav + ul) of my menu is static and written into the index.html

The submenu is an external html page that I open in the jQuery(document).ready  part, and added with append function.

My problem is located on the form:

[Good version / bad version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WrU4.png)

On the left, you can see a standard and static implementation,

With my solution, CSS seems to don't apply.

My code:

**index.html**:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="author" content="www.frebsite.nl" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width initial-scale=1.0 maximum-scale=1.0 user-scalable=yes" />

        <title>jQuery.mmenu demo</title>

        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/demo.css" />
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../dist/core/css/jquery.mmenu.all.css" />

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../dist/core/js/jquery.mmenu.min.all.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {  
                var $menu = $("#menu").mmenu({
                       "extensions": [
                          "pageshadow"
                       ],
                       "counters": true,
                       "navbar": {
                          "title": "Ressource List"
                       },
                       "navbars": [
                          {
                             "position": "top",
                             "content": [
                                "searchfield"
                             ]
                          },
                          {
                             "position": "top",
                             "content": [
                                "prev",
                                "title",
                                "close"
                             ]
                          }
                       ],
                       "sectionIndexer": true
                });

                var api = $("#menu").data( "mmenu" );

                api.bind( "init", function() {

                    $.ajax({
                        // options to retrieve the submenu
                        url:"include/menu.html",
                        type : 'GET',
                        dataType : 'html'
                    }).success(function(data) {
                        var $ul = $menu.find( "#panel" );
                        $ul.append(data);
                        $("body").addClass("body");
                    });                   

                });

                api.init( $("#panel") );

            });
        </script>   
    </head>

    <body>
        <!-- The page -->
        <div class="page">
            <div class="header">
               <a href="#menu"></a>
               Index
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- The menu -->
        <nav id="menu">
            <ul id="panel">

            </nav>
        </nav>
   </body>
</html>
```

**menu.html**

```
    <ul>
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><span>Room</span>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Room11</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Room12</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><span>Room2</span>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Room21</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Room22</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Update data</a></li>
</ul>
```

To simplify the problem, I've used the basic example included in the package: http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/download.html

Could you please help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Not sure if this is affecting anything but...

Your **ul** tag is missing a closing tag.

Also... in your success callback you have the code:

```
var $ul = $menu.find( "#panel" );
$ul.append(data);
```

If you are trying to get the first list in the panel. It should be:

```
var $ul = $menu.find( "#panel>ul" );
$ul.append(data);
```

jQuery.mmenu plugin appears to rearrange the markup.

### Works for 1 level:

```
var $menu = $('nav#menu').mmenu();
var api = $('nav#menu').data('mmenu');
$('#btnAdd').click(function () {
    var $ul = $menu.find('#test>ul');
    $ul.append('<li><a href="#">Home12</a></li>\
                <li><a href="#about">About us</a></li>\
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>');
});

<button id="btnAdd">Add</button>
<nav id="menu">
    <ul id="test"></ul>
</nav>
```

This only works for one level. If I try to add a nested list item it doesn't appear to work.

### Doesn't work for nested levels:

```
$ul.append('<li><a href="#">Home12</a></li>\
        <li><a id="about2" href="#about">About us</a><ul><li><a href="#about">About us</a></li></ul></li>\
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>');
```

### This github thread may help...

At the bottom of the thread the user **FrDH** provides an example that may help you. 
Link: https://github.com/FrDH/jQuery.mmenu/issues/57

Comment: Thank you for your answer, finaly i've found a workaround by adding class in my menu.html